# Extracting Meteor's Blaze templating engine

Tags: meteor

I would like to use Blaze templating engine in my application but without using Meteor. I was looking for standalone version but without effect. I've found this repo to export Blaze https://github.com/meteor/standalone-blaze-generator but it doesn't work. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. I would like to create some MiniMongo Collections and templates and to be able to update them reactively.

Does anyone know how to make standalone version of it?

EDIT:

It works, but I'm living this question for others.

Comment: meteor.github.io/blaze

Comment: Minimongo namespace would be available in Package.minimongo, use the LocalCollection class

Comment: Thanks for help, for now I'm trying to use only Blaze without Meteor Collections but I have problem with that. I try to render some template that has two EACH loops (nested). Everything renders properly but it doesn't rerender reactively when inner array changes. It seems like it compares only one level of nesting. I've tried few solutions (including Blaze.Var in Blaze.Var) but without successes. Can anyone help with that?

Comment: Blaze.Var isn't built to support complex structures, it is mostly useful for numbers/strings/simple objects. Either build your own reactive data source or use reactive-dict or minimongo. (https://meteor.hackpad.com/DRAFT-Understanding-Deps-aAXG6T9lkf6)

Comment: Thanks, seems to be good resource about deps. I've dealt with the problem. It appears that Blaze.Var makes simple === comparison if the object it holds changed. So I've just had to make _.clone of object and modify it. I haven't investigated it in details but it appears to update only that parts of DOM that change even I've replaced the whole object with its copy. I have to see through internals of Blaze to know how it works.

Comment: that's right, as I mentioned above, Blaze.Var has a simple === comparison.

Comment: Why not use plain Handlebars.js or Mustache?

Comment: @Luis because of lack of reactivity? I've actually manage to make it work but I don't remember what was the problem. So question is not relevant any more.